# Devexpress control got coverd by a layer after its parent form's size got changed

Tags: winforms, resize, devexpress

This is a dockpanel on the right side of the form. On the left ,threr is a TabPanel.

When resize the dockpanel, the tabPanel's size will be changed as well.

I use LayoutControl to customize ervery tab. And I placed MemoEdit and GridControl on the tab.

The thing is when the TabPanel's size get changed, the MemoEdit will be covered by a layer and the text in the MemoEdit will hide under this layer. This layer will disappear after clicking it.

Also when I switch different Tab, sometimes the GridControl will also be covered by a layer when I  switch back, as if that area is not painted. The GridControl will appear after refresh its data source.

Now I wanna konw how to avoid this situation and what can I do deal with it?

[image]